# Is there a way to backup the Windows recovery partition or recreate it on a Sony Vaio laptop?

Tags: sony-vaio, recovery-partition

My friend got a Sony Vaio laptop. Soon, I will install him Linux. But I want to back up the Windows 7's recovery partition that came pre-installed.

But on laptop, normally, when we boot up, they ask to press Fx (where x is a number I don't know, since its not my laptop) to launch the recovery partition. If I use Clonezilla to back up its recovery partition, how may I restore the functionality to press Fx to start the recovery partition, if I ever reformat the whole drive, and rewrite the back up to the drive?

Also, I heard that some computer vendor have a utility to create a set of Cd/DVD that will restore everything like factory. So it will restore the hidden partition. Is it the case for Sony's laptop? If yes, which utility? Does it will really recover the hidden recovery partition?

Do you recommend me Clonezilla for the backup?

Answer (score 0):

I use Macrium Reflect free, for backup partitions to external hdd. Maybe it can be usefull for you too.
Another good program is HDClone.

Answer (score 0):

You can create Recovery Disks with VAIO CARE application. There are two ways:

A) Backup as files: When you open it up, the Recovery Partition (usually H) comes out. So you can just copy and paste it's contents to another folder/drive.

B) Backup as ISOs: Download and install PhantomDrive utilily to emulate a DVD-R,  open the application and select "Recovery Options". Then just create a image as DVD-R and start to create.

I think when you install this recovery, it will partition your disks as 'factory reset'. I hope it helps.